# Populating tableView with firebase database

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to populate my tableView with firebase database.

Here is the code:-

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FriendsListViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var friendsListTableView: UITableView!

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var FIRControllerClassHandle : FIRControllerClass = FIRControllerClass()
var imageCell  = [UIImage]()
var username  = [String]()
var userDesc  = [String]()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    friendsListTableView.alpha = 0
    friendsListTableView.delegate = self
    friendsListTableView.dataSource = self

    populateTable({
        self.friendsListTableView.reloadData()
    })    
}

func populateTable(completionBlock : (() -> Void)){

    FIRControllerClassHandle.retrieveFriendListDatabase { (userIdA) in

        for a in 1 ... userIdA.count-1 {
            repeat {

                self.FIRControllerClassHandle.retrieveStorageForFriendListCell(userIdA[a] as! String, completion: { (image) in
                    print("image transferred in the friendlist block : \(image)")
                    print("user id in friendList : \(userIdA[a])")

                    self.imageCell.append(image) 
                })

                self.FIRControllerClassHandle.retrieveDatabaseForFriendListCell(userIdA[a] as! String, completion: { (profile) in


                    self.username.append((profile["username"] as? String)!)
                    self.userDesc.append((profile["briefDecription"] as? String)!)
                    completionBlock()   
                })
            } while(a <= userIdA.count-1)
        }
       }
    }

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("username count in the no of rows : \(username.count)")

    return username.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("username in cellForIndexpath : \(self.username)")

    let cell = friendsListTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendListCell") as! FriendsListTableViewCell

    cell.friendListProfileName.text = username[indexPath.row]
    cell.friendListProfileDescription.text = userDesc[indexPath.row]
    cell.friendListProfilePicture.image = imageCell[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

@IBAction func backBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let homePageScene = self.navigationController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomePageFeedViewControllerVC_ID") as! HomePageFeedViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homePageScene, animated: true)

}


}
```

This is running an infinite loop,
userIdA is the array in which i have stored all of my `user.uid` 
`self.FIRControllerClassHandle.retrieveStorageForFriendListCell` is function in the separate FIRController class that is returning the profile picture of the user
similarly `FIRControllerClassHandle.retrieveDatabaseForFriendListCell` for retrieving database
How would i go around this?

Comment: Why `for a in 1 ...` and not `0`?

Comment: Because i had to initialise the array at the backend and it needs a value to initialise itself... so at the 0 index their is a dummy value actual userIdA array start from 1.

Comment: Please try to avoid using array's - the will get you into trouble. The whole process can probably be greatly simplified but without seeing your Firebase structure it's hard to tell. Can you post a snippet of that as text please (no images) and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops nested within in each other:

```
   for a in 1 ... userIdA.count-1 {
        repeat{
            // ...
        }while(a <= userIdA.count-1)
    }
```

In the inner loop, `a` does not change, and therefore it will loop forever. I guess you just want the other loop.